# Electric Field in a Dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

Suppose a dielectric with no free charges is placed in an electric field (**E**). Once polarized, the total "volume bound charge " equals total "surface bound charge" right ? In this condition, the external field (**E**) is exactly equal and opposite to internal field (-**E**) right?

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234120/

Answer (score 1):

The field inside is not equal and opposite to the external field, since it is only a dielectric. A conductor can cancel the field inside totally, a dielectric can only partially cancel it. You will have to solve the problem of finding the electric field by solving boundary conditions of laplace's equation